# Radial derivative of the characteristic function of the unit disc in $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, partial-derivative, distribution-theory

I need help to answer this question from Hörmander,
Let $u$ be the characteristic function of the unit disc in $\mathbb  R^2$. 
Calculate $x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$.

The answer in the book is:
minus the arc length measure on the unit circle.

I am not sure if my calculations are right.

Let $\phi \in D(\mathbb R^2)$,

$$\left<x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}, \phi\right>= - \left<u,\frac{\partial {(x \phi(x,y))}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial (y \phi(x,y))}{\partial y} \right>= - \left<u, \operatorname{div} \begin{bmatrix}x \phi(x,y)\\y \phi(x,y)\end{bmatrix}\right>. $$

Now I think I have to use the Gauss-Green formula to get the length measure, but I don't know how to finish my answer if the above calculations are right.

Any help please would be perfect.

Comment: I changed the first row below to the second: $$<x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}, \phi>= - <u,\frac{\partial {(x \phi(x,y))}}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial (x \phi(x,y))}{\partial y} >= - <u, \operatorname{div} \begin{bmatrix}x \phi(x,y)\\x \phi(x,y)\end{bmatrix}>.$$ $${}$$ $$  \left<x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}, \phi\right>= - \left<u,\frac{\partial {(x \phi(x,y))}}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial (x \phi(x,y))}{\partial y} \right>= - \left<u, \operatorname{div} \begin{bmatrix}x \phi(x,y)\\x \phi(x,y)\end{bmatrix}\right>.$$

Comment: If you don't know how to typeset something like this, google "latex symbols" and you'll find it.

Comment: By "characteristic function", do you mean the indicator function? (I.e. equal to $1$ on the disk and to $0$ elsewhere?)

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Is there any material in Hörmander or elsewhere about that particular differential operator in general? $\qquad$

Comment: Here you find it . https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)

Comment: I think I should use the divergent theorem,

Comment: $ \int_{B(0,1)} \operatorname{div} \begin{bmatrix}x \phi(x,y)\\y \phi(x,y)\end{bmatrix} dx dy=\int_{\partial B(0,1)}  \begin{bmatrix}x \phi(x,y)\\y \phi(x,y)\end{bmatrix}. ? dS(x,y)  $ I am not sure here, what should I use for the interior unit normal.

Comment: Another typesetting comment: One normally puts a small space before $dx$ and $dy,$ thus $f(x,y) \,dx \,dy$ rather than $f(x,y) dx dy.$ It's not enough to have a blank space in the code. Notice how I coded MathJax in this comment. $\qquad$

Comment: Does the Wikipedia article to which you linked mention the differential operator $x\dfrac\partial {\partial x} + y\dfrac\partial {\partial y} \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: No, there isn't such thing in my book or Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \iint\limits_\text{unit disk} \left<u, \operatorname{div} \begin{bmatrix}x \varphi(x,y) \\ y \varphi(x,y) \end{bmatrix}\right> \, dA \\[10pt]
= {} & \int\limits_\text{boundary} \Big( (x\varphi(x,y), y\varphi(x,y)) \cdot (\text{outward unit normal}) \, d(\text{arc length}) \Big) \\
& \qquad\qquad\text{by the divergence theorem} \\[15pt]
= {} & \int\limits_\text{boundary} (x\varphi(x,y),y\varphi(x,y)) \cdot (x,y)\, d(\text{arc length}) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int\limits_\text{boundary} (x^2 + y^2)\varphi(x,y) \, d(\text{arc length}) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_\text{boundary} \varphi(x,y)\,d(\text{arc length})
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for all answers, I don’t understand how did you get the outward unit normal? Please can you explain.

Comment: @AdamJC : The unit disk is $x^2+y^2=1.$ The vector from $(0,0)$ to a typical point on the disk is $(x,y).$ That is a unit vector since it's a unit disk. Now observe that that meets the circle at a right angle. In particular, differentiation of both sides of $x^2+y^2=1$ yields $2x\,dx+2y\,dy = 0,$ so $dy/dx = -x/y.$ That means the slope of the curve at the point $(x,y)$ is $-x/y.$ The slope of the vector $(x,y)$ is $y/x.$ Since the product of those two slopes is $-1,$ they're at right angles to each other. So the unit normal is $(x,y). \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) three ways of performing this computation. In what follows, $D$ is the unit disk and $\mathbf 1_A$ is the function that equals $1$ on $A$ and $0$ otherwise.

1. Consider the formal integral 
   $$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} (x\partial_x+y\partial_y)(\mathbf 1_D)\,f(x, y)\, dx\,dy, $$ 
   where $f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^2)$ and integrate by parts. (This formal integral is often written as a braket, like in the post by the OP). This is the method of the OP and of Micheal's answer.
2. Consider a smoothed version of $\mathbf 1_D$, such as the one obtained by convolution against the heat kernel $K(t, x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2t}/(4\pi t)$, and observe that 
   $$(x\partial_x+y\partial_y)\mathbf 1_D \ast K(t, x,y) = \mathbf 1_D \ast (x\partial_x+y\partial_y)K(t, x, y),$$ 
   then compute $(x\partial_x+y\partial_y)K(t, x, y)$ and let $t\to 0^+$ in the convolution in the right-hand side.
3. Observe that $x\partial_x+y\partial_y$ is the generator of dilations, in the sense that for any distribution $T$ one has that 
   $$\partial_\lambda T(\lambda x , \lambda y)|_{\lambda=1} =(x\partial_x+y\partial_y)T(x, y),$$ and then compute the derivative in the left-hand side.

The method 3 can be carried out as follows: taking an arbitrary $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$, and observing that $\mathbf 1_D(\lambda x, \lambda y)= \mathbf 1_{\lambda^{-1}D}(x, y)$, we compute 
$$\partial_\lambda \iint_{\mathbb R^2} \mathbf 1_{\lambda^{-1}D}f(x, y)\, dx\,dy = \partial_\lambda \iint_{\lambda^{-1}D} f\, dx\,dy = -\lambda^{-2}\int_{\partial\lambda^{-1}D} f\, ds.$$
The last formula is the derivative of an integral over a moving region, and can be found, e.g. in Evans book on PDEs, in the Appendix (actually, this formula is a special case of [Reynolds transport theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem)). Here $ds$ denotes the arc-length measure on the circle. Notice that the $-\lambda^{-2}$ factor comes from the differentiation of $\lambda^{-1}$. Evaluating this expression at $\lambda=1$ yields the desired conclusion. $\Box$